# Leetcode questions 26 "Remove Duplicates from sorted array"

Tags: python

I do not think I understand how replit works, the output that the code in Leetcode is returning is different from the one I receive when I run the code in Replit, can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work? I know there are resources that tell you how to do the code by I just question why I am getting different outputs. Thank you for any help in advance.

This is the code:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        print(nums)
        nums1=[]
        k=0
        for i in nums:
            
            if i not in nums1:
                nums1.append(i)
                k+=1
            else:
                pass
        print(f'{k},{nums1}')
```

Comment: What are the outputs of Leetcode vs the outputs of Replit?

Comment: The LeetCode problem says you're supposed to remove the duplicates *in place*. You're not modifying the input list, you're creating a new list.

Comment: You're also not returning `k`.